# What is the Biblical Basis for the view that God's Will is always good?

Tags: biblical-basis, will-of-god

In responding to the Question
"Is it good because God wills it, or does God will it because it is good?"

Someone said and I quote:

> The foundation of Goodness is God. God's will is everything concerning Him, which eventually is Good.  God wills it, to show himself, that He is Good; and it is good because it is of God.

My question is based on this supposition:

"God's will is everything concerning Him, which eventually is good.

Does this have biblical basis ?

Comment: I think you should reformat this question and find out what Christian faith perspective that person is asking from before just querying the community "how true is that". We can't answer broad questions like this.

Comment: Thanks I have edited to suit

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that's going to land you with objective answers.  But I'll "un-close" it for now.  Ideally a you'd ask about a doctrine in relation to a creed, not "where is this in the Bible?"

Comment: It is self evident that God, the source of all, the Most High, and the Creator of all things, is righteous according to his own self and not according to any external rule or 'greater' force or rule than he (since none greater than he can exist). Multitudes of scriptures state this in a multitude of ways.

Comment: Okay Thanks Peter. Ild learn how to ask more questions here.  I am more active in Bible Stack exchange. As my questions here are always closed

Comment: @faith ha, yeah, I understand.  Good questions usually include something about a known faith tradition (Catholic, Baptist, etc..).  Lots of people don't seem to care for that because they're either not Christians or non-denominational or they don't know why it would make a difference.   On the other hand,  If you're asking about a famous quote (like by C.S. Lewis or St. Augustine), we can usually extrapolate from that the doctrine.  But this is just some anonymous person on Stackexchange.  Thats why this question probably will get closed - I'd imagine someone will try to answer first though.

Comment: So who is this "someone" who said this?  What is the actual source of this aphorism?

Comment: @FaithMendel, the more specific a question is the more likely it is to be answered. The more details of your research it contains, and where you got stuck, the more likely people are to understand the question. People need to be able to put themselves into your perspective in order to give good answers. ¶ In this case it refers to "the Question" without saying where that question appeared, and uses the indefinite "someone said" without saying who that someone was and where they said it. Both *could* be something you just made up for the purpose of asking this question (I'm not saying you did).

Comment: @FaithMendel, what you are asking about is a variation of the [Euthyphro dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyphro_dilemma).  You might look what [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) has to say about it, and then present your best summary of it here and *then* ask whether it has a biblical basis.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth The person isn't on stack exchange , I had a chat with the person and we had the conversation.  I have see. Questions here that was approved and up voted that is similar as this.  I wonder why this is a different case

Comment: What would it change if I presented a summary of the Euthyphro dilemma, since my question is not from the dilemma, but from the answer given to it ?